# Button on form not working or showing any text

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I am trying to create a custom title bar for my form. For this reason I have:

```
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
```

I've positioned two custom buttons for minimising and closing as such:

```
// Close
// 
this.Close.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
this.Close.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
this.Close.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
this.Close.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
this.Close.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonFace;
this.Close.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(376, 0);
this.Close.Name = "Close";
this.Close.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(27, 23);
this.Close.TabIndex = 1;
this.Close.Text = "X";
this.Close.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
this.Close.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Close_Click);
// 
// Hide
// 
this.Hide.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
this.Hide.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
this.Hide.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
this.Hide.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
this.Hide.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonFace;
this.Hide.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(346, 0);
this.Hide.Name = "Hide";
this.Hide.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 23);
this.Hide.TabIndex = 0;
this.Hide.Text = "---";
this.Hide.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
```

Which Is meant to look like this:

[image]

However, for some reason when I run the app they appear like this (without the text):

[image: What the APP draws]

Also, I've coded it so that upon clicking the `Close` button this code is run:

```
private void Close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

However, when I click close nothing happens.

Can anybody point as to what is wrong with my code. Or what I have to add to fix it.

#### Edit:

Turns out, when I change the button colour to red the cross shows, but it is black, not white!

Comment: why don't you use image button instead of just button. There will be no need of text. Use a background image on that button and your problem is solved

Comment: I know, I can use an image. I am just curious as to why this code does not work

Comment: Also @patel, this does not explain why nothing happens when I click close

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint and test if that hits when you click the button . And also KcDOD comment about names is correct change names and clean project and rebuilt it again.

Comment: Hard to guess, sounds like you've been hacking the system colors and SystemColors.ButtonFace is no longer the default battleship gray but is now black.  Easier to just turn down the brightness setting of your monitor.  Your Click event handler doesn't work because you've hidden the Form.Close() method with the Close button, do pay attention to the warnings you get in the Error List window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working perfectly.I have tried it.I am attaching all files Please change namespace and try it.

Designer.cs code

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
```

{
    partial class Form3
    {
        /// 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// 
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.Close = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.Hide = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // Close
        // 
        this.Close.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.Close.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.Close.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
        this.Close.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.Close.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonFace;
        this.Close.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(260, 0);
        this.Close.Name = "Close";
        this.Close.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(27, 23);
        this.Close.TabIndex = 1;
        this.Close.Text = "X";
        this.Close.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        this.Close.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Close_Click);
        // 
        // Hide
        // 
        this.Hide.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
        this.Hide.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.Hide.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
        this.Hide.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.Hide.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonFace;
        this.Hide.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(230, 0);
        this.Hide.Name = "Hide";
        this.Hide.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 23);
        this.Hide.TabIndex = 0;
        this.Hide.Text = "---";
        this.Hide.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // Form3
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Hide);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Close);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Name = "Form3";
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Form3";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Button Close;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button Hide;
}
```

}

Close Button Click

```
 private void Close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

On Close Button Click i have done code for close the form.It also working.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing your like

```
this.Close.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonFace;
```

with

```
lblExample.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to change Design names of Close and Hide.

Change `Close` and `Hide` to some other name.. Else there will be `namespace` conflicts with Form's Hide and Form's Close. Also remember, without `FormBorderStyle` you will not able to move the form as usual..

Try following, This at least worked for me.

Note : The change is I have positioned the controls in the place I want them to see rather than using Drawing

```
public Mainform()
{

 InitializeComponent();

 this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;

 // Close
 // 
 this.CloseBut.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
 this.CloseBut.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
 this.CloseBut.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
 this.CloseBut.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
 this.CloseBut.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonFace;
 //this.CloseBut.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(376, 0);
 this.CloseBut.Name = "Close";
 this.CloseBut.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(27, 23);
 this.CloseBut.TabIndex = 1;
 this.CloseBut.Text = "X";
 this.CloseBut.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
 this.CloseBut.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Close_Click);
 // 
 // Hide
 // 
 this.HideBut.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
 this.HideBut.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
 this.HideBut.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
 this.HideBut.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
 this.HideBut.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonFace;
 //this.HideBut.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(346, 0);
 this.HideBut.Name = "Hide";
 this.HideBut.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 23);
 this.HideBut.TabIndex = 0;
 this.HideBut.Text = "---";
 this.HideBut.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
 this.HideBut.Click += new EventHandler(this.hide_click);

}

private void hide_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowState=FormWindowState.Minimized;
}

private void Close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Simply try the provided code with a sample form.. then adopt it to the solution .. try for that

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same issue where my textbox was not displaying text in one of my projects while it worked in all the others. I found that somehow my font color for buttons got changed to the same color as the default color of the button, so the text was there, it just wasn't visible.